# Merge 2 columns in Excel and make data permanent

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, merge, concatenation

I know how to concatenate  2 columns in Excel, but I want the new column to become merged data NOT dependent on the formula. The reason is I can't copy the results into a new column.

I.e.
|col 1  |    col2   |  col 3 |

---

| 500   | .00 USD | 500.00 USD |

Column 3 has to be stable and not dependent on the other 2 columns.   The Merge functions in Excel Mac  only remove the info in column 2 ... weird. That isn't a merge, that is erase!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Range- go to Data- From Table/Range:

[image]

2. Change the Column 1 format to Text- select Replace Current:

[image]

3. Go to Add Column- select Custom Column- enter the formula:

   ```
   =[Column1]&[Column2]
   ```

[image]

4. Go to Home- Close & Load:

[image]